# How to add custom dynamic theming in ant design

Tags: dynamic, antd, customization, theming

I want to change the theme of my entire application based on the theme coming from API.

My current implementation:

I used these steps mentioned in Antd [Docs](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme) which works perfectly for a static custom theme. ( For any change made in the config the server has to be re-run )

This would not fit my current requirement as the app can't be stopped and re-run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Antd supports dynamic theming

You can follow the official Antd [Docs](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme) to implement this.

Here is a simple [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-dynamic-theming-0xne60?file=/demo.tsx) to get started.

However if you choose to not to go with experimental approach there is an another way to implement dynamic theming using a [plugin](https://github.com/mzohaibqc/antd-theme-generator).

Check this simple [guide](https://medium.com/@mzohaib.qc/ant-design-live-theme-588233ea2bbc) to get started

Note: This project is not maintained actively. Use this with caution.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have customized Ant design v5 theme to support multiple themes just need to change the colors.ts file and algorithms(dark, default) which I mentioned below and here I am sharing with proper folder structure.

Prerequisites:

1. Understanding for ant design v5 theming.
2. Understanding of TypeScript you can ignore types if you are using Javascript only.

Resources:

1. https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme
2. https://ant.design/theme-editor

You can play with the themes to get exact config property and while changing, you will get to know what exactly is changing by using theme-editor.

Ant design theme editor will be very helpful in your development.

Create a below folder structure for you react app.

[image]

This is single source of truth of colors. I have used to modify the base, token and components colors.

```
color.ts
export type ColorsType = {
  colorBgBase: string;
  colorPrimary: string;
  colorSecondary: string;
  colorTertiary: string;
  bgWhite: string;
};

export const colors: ColorsType = {
  colorBgBase: '#000000',
  colorPrimary: '#f59600',
  colorSecondary: '#1e2021',
  colorTertiary: '#3c3d40',
  bgWhite: '#ffffff',
};
```

token.ts store all the config value, margin, padding, colors below i have modified the primary, base and cotainer color. By default they have all the tokens and even we can access and use them using useToken hook provided by Ant design.

```
token.ts
import { colors } from '@/theming/colors';
import { AliasToken } from '@/common/SSComp/SSComp';
const { colorBgBase, colorPrimary, colorSecondary, bgWhite } = colors;

export const token: Partial<AliasToken> = {
  colorPrimary: colorPrimary,
  colorBgBase: colorBgBase,
  colorBgContainer: colorSecondary,
  colorWhite: bgWhite,
  fontSizeSM: 0,
  lineHeightHeading2: 0,
};
```

Using a component.ts file, you can customize specific Antd components by adjusting their margin, padding, color, and other properties to meet your requirements. In the example below, I have modified the Menu & Layout component, same principles apply to every Antd component.

```
components.ts
import { colors } from '@/theming/colors';
import { ComponentsConfig } from '@/common/SSComp/SSComp';
const { colorPrimary, colorSecondary, colorTertiary, bgWhite } = colors;

export const components: ComponentsConfig = {
  Layout: {
    headerBg: colorSecondary,
    siderBg: colorSecondary,
  },
  Menu: {
    itemColor: colorPrimary,
    itemSelectedColor: bgWhite,
    itemHoverBg: colorTertiary,
    itemSelectedBg: colorTertiary,
    colorBgContainer: colorSecondary,
    itemBorderRadius: 20,
    colorIconHover: bgWhite,
    itemHoverColor: colorPrimary,
  },
};
```

This is the MainConfig which you need to use as AppWrapper.

```
themeConfig.ts
import { theme, ThemeConfig } from '@/common/SSComp/SSComp';
import { token } from '@/theming/token';
import { components } from '@/theming/components';

export const themeConfig: ThemeConfig = {
  token,
  components,
  algorithm: theme.darkAlgorithm,
};
```

App.tsx

```
import { themeConfig } from '@/theming/themeConfig';

<ConfigProvider theme={themeConfig}>
    <AppLayout>
       <CustomComp>Main app wrapper</CustomComp>
    </AppLayout>
</ConfigProvider>
```

Access token config using below approach.

```
import { theme } from 'antd';
const { useToken } = theme;
const { token } = useToken();

Got the token, Now you can use the property.
Example:
suppose want to access colorPrimary and apply to a div.

const { colorPrimary } = token;
<div style={{ backgroundColor:colorPrimary }></div>
```